# How to get sticker in comment from Facebook Webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I'm doing a web application to manage comment from facebook fanpage.
I've subscribed webhook in field **feed**

[image]

I comment in my fanpage:

[image]

And JSON response from webhook like that:

[image]

I don't know how to get both message and sticker and how to know what comment have sticker.
Thanks for reading my question :)

Comment: Make an API call, and request the `attachment` field of the comment object.

Comment: Thanks you. I can get by this way. But with many comment, I may reach request limit :D.